# tuple iteration vectorization

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have a pandas code, that is iterating tuples, I am trying to vectorize it.

list of tuples I am iterating if of this kind:

```
[('Morden', 35672, 'Morden Hall Park, Surrey'),
 ('Morden', 73995, 'Morden Hall Park, Surrey'),
 ('Newbridge', 120968, 'Newbridge, Midlothian'),
 ('Stroud', 127611, 'Stroud, Gloucestershire')]
```

the working tuples iterating code is:

```
for tuple_ in result_tuples:
    listing_looking_ins1.loc[:,'looking_in']\ 
    [(listing_looking_ins1.listing_id ==tuple_[1]) &
     (listing_looking_ins1.looking_in ==tuple_[0])] = tuple_[2]
```

I have tried to write a func to use with apply method, but it does not work:

```
result_tuples_df = pd.DataFrame(result_tuples)

def replace_ (row):
    row.loc[:,'looking_in'][(listing_looking_ins1.listing_id\ 
    \==result_tuples_df[1]) &
    (listing_looking_ins1.looking_in\==result_tuples_df[0])] \
     = result_tuples_df[2]

listing_looking_ins1.apply(replace_, axis=1)
```

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is your expected output? Are you trying to get the last word from the third element in the tuples or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your list of tuples to DataFrame and merge it with the original:

```
result_tuples_df = pd.DataFrame(result_tuples,
                                columns=['listing_id', 'looking_in', 'result'])

df = listing_looking_ins1.merge(result_tuples_df)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  listing_id  looking_in                    result
0     Morden       35672  Morden Hall Park, Surrey
1     Morden       73995  Morden Hall Park, Surrey
2  Newbridge      120968     Newbridge, Midlothian
3     Stroud      127611   Stroud, Gloucestershire
```

And then if you want to have the result in the `looking_in` column:

```
df.drop('looking_in', 1).rename(columns={'result': 'looking_in'})
```

Output:

```
  listing_id                looking_in
0     Morden  Morden Hall Park, Surrey
1     Morden  Morden Hall Park, Surrey
2  Newbridge     Newbridge, Midlothian
3     Stroud   Stroud, Gloucestershire
```

P.S. In your code you're setting values with:

```
listing_looking_ins1.loc[:,'looking_in'][...] = ...
```

This is setting values on a copy of the DataFrame. Please refer to [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas) on why and how you should avoid doing this

P.P.S. Since you asked about vectorisation and using apply, you may also want to have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/24871316/6792743 on performance of different operations

Comment: Thank you! It is so simple...  I have done this so many times